# Correct way to get output on Postman - which parameter to put where?

Tags: ruby, api, post, postman, crud

I am trying to see if API call is functioning.

Is this the correct method to get POST output on Postman - especially where to put the parameters and headers. I tried GET also to get error

> Method not allowed (code:405)

screenshot:

[image: please click here for the output screenshot here]

The original ruby code to be tested -

```
 uri          =  URI 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens'
    data         = { 'auth' => { "RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials" => { 'username' => 'beamteam' , 'apiKey' => '****' }} }
    json_headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json"}
    http   = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, 443
    http.use_ssl = true
```

Which http method is suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The response message you got says that you are missing MIME media type and authorization data.

1. you need to add the missing header field.
2. for the authorization use postman authorization field - see screenshot.

   [image]

Comment: Hello Nir, it still gives same result. Which http method do I use?

Comment: if you want data from the server than GET, if you send data to the server than POST.

Comment: Hello Nir, When I use GET, I receive :{
    "methodNotAllowed": {
        "code": 405
    }
}

Comment: and for POST, headers section shows as this (next to Body and Cookies) - https://i.imgur.com/TEkCRMv.png; please suggest. Is it authentication issue for 405?

Comment: When we do POSTs we pass an API key via the Authorization key in the header not in the params.